# Delete the node from last in link list in java

Tags: java

it is method of deleting the last node.

```
public void delete_at_end(int data) {
    Node ppre;
    if (head== null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("cannot delete");
    } else {
        if (head == last) {
            head = null;
            last = null;

         } else {
            ppre = head;
            while (ppre.next != null && ppre.data!=data) {
                ppre = ppre.next;
            }
            last=ppre;
            last.next = null;

        }
    }

}
```

original output :`19 -> 9 -> 5 -> 4 -> 17 -> 16 -> null`

after deleting the last  node : `19 -> 9 -> 5 -> 4 -> 17 -> 16 -> null`

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: @Joffrey I thought you died last episode  |=^]

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc Haha +1 for humor, but you could spoil a lot of people ^^

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc clearly he is a zombie

Comment: Wait..... Joffrey dies?!?! But there still is no question to this post

Comment: What is the purpose of your method? To delete the last element of the list? To delete the element with the specified value? To delete the last element of the list if it has the specified value?

Comment: You either can choose to delete the last node or choose to delete a node with a specific value or you can do both. In this case, you are doing both.  Do you mean just to do one of those?

Comment: Also, the last line of code will throw NPE if the data is not contained in any node. (I'm ignoring braces when I say "last line")

Comment: Did the OP throw his question here and fly away? :D

Answer (score 0):

This is not a method for deleting the last node, it is a method for deleting all nodes after the node with value equal to data, unless it is one node long in which case it deletes it all. (assuming you have a head and last node that are globally available of course)

```
public void delete_at_end(int data) {
    Node ppre;
    if (head== null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("cannot delete");  // there is nothing to delete
    } else {
        if (head == last) { // if the head is the only node, delete it
            head = null;
            last = null;

         } else {
            ppre = head;  // otherwise we cycle through everything, checking if it is equal to the data we passed in
            while (ppre.next != null && ppre.data!=data) {
                ppre = ppre.next;
            }
            last=ppre;  // when we find the data we passed in, we set it equal to the last node
            last.next = null; // and terminate the rest of the list

        }
    }

}
```

As mentioned in the comments above, calling .next on a null will cause an error, so if you get to the end of the list, and set ppre = ppre.next (a null value), then set last = ppre, you will call .next of a null value.